# Problem trying to filter a dat or csv file based on the values of the first column using awk?

Tags: awk

I have a dat file:

```
> head file.dat 
"201731","474","1000522966","0.2670"
"201732","474","1000522966","0.3163"
"201733","474","1000522966","0.3902"
"201734","474","1000522966","0.4479"
"201735","474","1000522966","0.5960"
"201736","474","1000522966","0.2598"
"201737","474","1000522966","0.3937"
"201738","474","1000522966","0.3558"
"201739","474","1000522966","0.3344"
"201740","474","1000522966","0.5544"
```

I would like to filter it so that I keep only the lines with "201731".

I have tried several awk commands:

```
awk -F , '{ if ($1 == "201731") { print } }' file.dat | head
awk -F '","' 'BEGIN {OFS=","} { if (toupper($1) == "201731")  print }' file.dat | head 
awk -F '","' '{ if (toupper($1) == "201731")  print }' file.dat | head 
awk -F ',' '{ if (toupper($1) == "201731")  print }' file.dat | head
```

None of them work. 
They all run without errors and then I get an empty prompt without any output.

I'm using awk version GNU Awk 3.1.7.

An almost identical question exists on this site with an answer, but even that didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command:

```
awk '/"201731"/' file
```

will output only lines with 201731.

If I misunderstood your task, correct me

Comment: Is there a way of doing this for multiple strings? Something like **awk '/"201731" or "201732" or "201733/' file** ?

Comment: @Alex Kinman, yes there is `awk '/"20173[1-3]"/' file`

Comment: Thanks, one more question though. This works for the example I gave, but when I tried it for a wider range, I can't get it to work. I tried  **awk '/"2017[38-42]"/' file**, which threw and error  and **awk '/"2017[38,39,40,41,42]"/' file** which returned an empty file.

Comment: try this: `awk '/"20173(38|39|40|41|42)"/' file`. And this topic is outdated, create another one next time.

Answer (score 2):

Your code:

```
awk -F , '{ if ($1 == "201731") { print } }' file.dat
```

This is almost correct, apart from the fact that `$1`, when read with `,` as field delimiter, will also contain the double quotes present in the data. The other attempts are similar in nature, but I'm not sure what you think `toupper()` would do on a number.

You may simply use `$1 ~ /201731/` to match the first field against a regular expression (or `$1 ~ /^"201731"$/` to fully specify the contents of the field from the start of the field to the very end, to protect from false positives), or, if you want to check against a fixed string rather than doing a regular expression match, test the field against `\"201731\"`.

So, you have either

```
awk -F ',' '$1 ~ /^"201731"$/' file.in
```

or

```
awk -F ',' '$1 == "\"201731\""' file.in
```